# I can't edit posts anymore after PhpMyAdmin tables repair

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've tried to repair and optimize Wordpress tables in PhpMyAdmin. There was query error (but I didn't save it) and now I can't create or update posts and repair/optimize "posts" table in PHPMyAdmnin.

When I'm trying to repair/optimize tables, then I got that message - #2013 - Lost connection to mysql server during query
https://i.stack.imgur.com/43BMn.png
It happens for "posts" table. It is 1.5 GB. "posts" table is InnoDB, other Wordpress tables are MyISAM. Is it normal?

When I want to create or update posts, then it's loading all the time:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU75U.png
I was waiting for 5 minutes, but it doesn't work.

I have contacted with my host, but they will look into this in 24-48 hours. Maybe you know how to fix this now.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Importing backup database **via SSH** (not phpmyadmin) worked.